# Adding subviews to tableHeaderView with UISearchBar in iOS7 misbehaves

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

How can one add two simple UILabels to a TableHeaderView and retain the default searchbar behavior of the search display controller in iOS7?

**Or, visually:**

Why does this code:

```
UIView *tableHeadView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;   

UILabel *tableHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 36, 320, 30)];
[tableHeaderLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
tableHeaderLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
tableHeaderLabel.text = @"Questions"

UILabel *tableHeaderPrononce = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 30)];
[tableHeaderPrononce setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
tableHeaderPrononce.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
tableHeaderPrononce.text = @"test test test test";

[tableHeadView addSubview:tableHeaderLabel];
[tableHeadView addSubview:tableHeaderPrononce];
```

added to a UITableViewController viewDidLoad event (which contains a UISearchDisplayerController)
gives this lovely result in iOS6:
[image: Normal] 
[image: While searching]
and this horrible terrible result in iOS7:
[image: Normal]
[image: While searching]

**The behavior:**
During normal mode the UILabels I added are not shown. while search is active the UILabels suddenly appear ON TOP OF the table cells and does not scroll away

In addition I am getting crashes while searching in iOS 7 which never occurred on iOS6. Probably not related to this piece of code but nevertheless I should mentioned that.

I tried all I could find on SO about fixing this issue but always something else breaks or disappears (mainly the UISearchBar).

Help

Comment: If there was any way to link to the project on github, I would take a look at both issues for you.

Comment: Its not on git but all the relevant code is here

Answer (score 7):

Look dude, before you modify your code or get frustrated with the behavior of the iOS7, it is advised to go through the [UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/ContentViews.html) given by apple.

After reading this you will get to know, why the grouped style tableView is looking annoying is not at all annoying from ios7 point of view. ***Each group extends the full width of the screen.***

Moreover the `UISearchBar` behavior can be controlled if you read through [Search Bar and Scope Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html)

I hope that helps. Should you need all the code, please let us know. we can provide sample.

**Here is Sample Code as Required**  Adding UISearchBar to View rather than TableViewHeader

- Adding `UISearchBar` to `self.view`

  ```
  searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, 320, 44.0f)];
  searchBar.delegate         = self;
  searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
  [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
  ```
- Adding `UITableView` to `self.view`

  ```
  tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  tableView.delegate         = self;
  tableView.dataSource       = self;
  tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
  [self.view addSubview:tableView];
  ```
- Creating and Adding `UITableView.tableHeaderView`

  ```
  UILabel *tableHeaderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 15)];
  [tableHeaderLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  tableHeaderLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
  tableHeaderLabel.text = @"Questions";
  tableHeaderLabel.alpha = 0.9;

  UILabel *tableHeaderPrononce = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 14, 320, 15)];
  [tableHeaderPrononce setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  tableHeaderPrononce.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15];
  tableHeaderPrononce.text = @"test test test test";
  tableHeaderPrononce.alpha = 0.7;

  UIView *aHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
  [aHeaderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [aHeaderView addSubview:tableHeaderLabel];
  [aHeaderView addSubview:tableHeaderPrononce];
  tableView.tableHeaderView = aHeaderView;
  ```

Here are the results:

[image: Normal Appearance]

[image: SearchBar]

***SearchDisplayController***

```
// Create search controller
searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate   = self;
searchController.delegate                = self;
```

Comment: So looks like you better need the code. I will give you the code in some time. Thanks.

Comment: Look at my edit. I will be adding more code if you want the UISearchBar to be added as part of tableHeaderView.

Comment: OK, cool thanks!
thing is you've created a standalone UISearchBar, where mine is linked to UISearchDisplayController. In addition it is already appearing on the TableViewHeader, in case I don't added those 2 UILabels..

Comment: No, it is linked to UISearchDisplayController. Since that code was not required to be shown, I have not mentioned it here.

Comment: Plz expect a delay in my response as I am doing it from mobile with minimal Internet access. :-(

Comment: the way you offered it is not linked - so search performs nothing.
I think correct way is to somehow disconnect and reconnect the     self.searchDisplayController.searchBar to the tableHeadView (aHeaderView)

Comment: For this, you should just add a tag value like 9999 to the searchbar and add it to the aSearchView. Then initialize the searchDisplayController by '(UISearchBar*)[tableView.tableHeaderView viewWithTag:9999]' . This will link it. I will try to give you proper code once I am back on my Mac. Sorry for improper formatting as using mobile. Since this discussion is going long, use my email Id to conversation more on this. tiwari.balram@gmail.com

Comment: I still can't see a solution how to add two simple UILabels to the table header view when a UISearchBar exists.. and why does the ios6 code works 100% and the iOS 7 breaks horribly

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by UITableViewDelegate method shown below:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```